# apache/2.4.29 (ubuntu) server at localhost port 80

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu

I am trying to run [openEMR](https://github.com/openemr/openemr) project in Eclipse on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I have downloaded the project and installed the dependencies using below command.

```
composer install --no-dev
npm install
npm run build
composer dump-autoload -o
```

I followed this tutorial to run the application but still I got the below error.

[image: > apache/2.4.29 (ubuntu) server at localhost port 80]

The project is present inside this folder.

[image]

And the configurations in Eclipse are:

[image]

[image]

I tried like below as well:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a resource in your web browser which does not exist in your apache2.
The directory public_html is your Document Root. Therefore, you have to specify a resource that is relative to your Document Root.

Try
http://localhost/openemr-6_0_0/index.php

Comment: I tried this as well but it did not work. The same error.

Comment: How to confirm that the resource is not present in apache2.

Comment: Try to put a simple .html file in the Document Root. If you can't access it neither, your server is misconfigured and does not point to your public_html directory.